# single cross puzzle, optimizing the probability

Tags: probability, optimization

The question:

> A random line segment of length $D$ is chosen on a plane marked with an
> infinite checkerboard grid (i.e., a unit side length square grid).
> What length $D$ maximizes the probability that the segment crosses
> exactly one line on the checkerboard grid, and what is this maximal
> probability?

Here's my approach:

We can simplify the problem and look at a single square. It will never intersect this square once and another square once [if we set the center of the segment at point $P$ in this square], it would always cross this one twice before crossing another.

Let $Z$ be the event that we cross exactly one of this square's edges. $Z$ is uniquely described by one of $L, T, R, B$, where each corresponds to intersecting the left (top, right, bottom) side and none of the others. By symmetry, each one has an equivalent probability, so we will just explore $R$. Imagine the square we are considering bottom left coordinate $(0, 0)$ and top right coordinate $(1, 1)$.

The way I will approach this is to choose a point $P$ in the square, choose $\theta$, then have two segments, each $\frac{D}{2}$ extend out in directions $\theta$ and $\pi + \theta$.

Point $P = (x, y)$, where $x, y$ are selected from Uniform$(0, 1)$, that is, $P(x < k) = k$.

I aim to find $P(R | \theta, D)$. Let's break this into cases $P(Y, X | \theta, D)$, where $X$ is the event it crosses the right and not the left and $Y$ is the event it crosses neither the top not bottom.

The $y$ coordinate's of the tails of the segment must not intersect $0$ or $1$. Let us restrict $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ because of symmetry (and we use the fact $\theta$ is positive). Formally, $y + \frac{D}{2}sin\theta < 1$ and $y - \frac{D}{2}sin\theta > 0$. This ultimately yields $\frac{D}{2}sin\theta < y < 1 - \frac{D}{2}sin\theta$. Because $y \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$, we have $$P(Y | \theta, D) = 1 - Dsin\theta$$.

We follow a similar method for $P(X | \theta, D)$. We can bound $0 <\theta < \frac{pi}{2}$. We will have a right-only intersection when $x - \frac{D}{2}cos\theta > 0$ and $x + \frac{D}{2}cos\theta > 1$, ultimately yielding $1 - \frac{D}{2}cos\theta < x < 1$, giving
$$ P(X | \theta, D) = \frac{D}{2}cos\theta$$.

We can set up the total probability $P(Z | \theta, D) = P(X| \theta, D)P(Y| \theta, D)$.
$$P(Z | \theta, D) = (1 - Dsin\theta)(\frac{D}{2}cos\theta), 0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$$.

This ends up giving $D = 1$ and $P(Z | D = 1) = \frac{1}{2\pi}$. The correct solution is $D = 1$ and $P(Z | D = 1) = \frac{2}{\pi}$, which means I just got lucky with the $D = 1$, as I was optimizing the wrong eqn. Could someone point me in the direction I should've headed for this question.

EDIT: I forgot to multiply by 4 :)